# (Javascript) How do i remove the 'undefined' after alert box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, undefined

```
/* Validating Captcha Function */
function ValidCaptcha() {
    var str1 = removeSpaces(document.getElementById('txtCaptcha').value);
    var str2 = removeSpaces(document.getElementById('txtCompare').value);

    if (str1 == str2) {
        alert("請按OKAY兩次 (Please Press OKAY Twice To Submit)");
        document.getElementById('contact-form').action = "/send_form_email.php";
    }
    else {
        alert("請輸入正確的號碼 (Please Enter The Correct Vertification Number)");
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
    }
}
```

This is the code i use for a javascript captcha element on my website, this code works perfectly, however after the alert boxes pops up, an 'Undefined' will always follow. I have already tried return true and return false with no luck. MANY THANKS <3

BTW this is how i initiate the javascript form onsubmit in HTML

```
<form id="contact-form" class="form-horizontal"  method="post" onsubmit="return alert(ValidCaptcha());">
```

Comment: When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: try `onsubmit="return  ValidCaptcha(event);` and change your function to `function ValidCaptcha(event)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are calling submit

```
onsubmit="return alert(ValidCaptcha());"
```

You have an alert. Your ValidCaptcha does not return anything, hence why it is undefined. Also alert returns nothing so makes no sense.

Should just be

```
onsubmit="return ValidCaptcha();"
```

and now you should be returning a boolean.

```
function ValidCaptcha() {
  var str1 = removeSpaces(document.getElementById('txtCaptcha').value);
  var str2 = removeSpaces(document.getElementById('txtCompare').value);

  if (str1 == str2) {
    alert("請按OKAY兩次 (Please Press OKAY Twice To Submit)"); 
    document.getElementById('contact-form').action = "/send_form_email.php";
    return true
  } else {
    alert("請輸入正確的號碼 (Please Enter The Correct Verification Number)");  //<Vertification should be  Verification
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Now that you have told me, it seems so stupid that i would return an alert XD, I have changed and also added return true and return false and it works PERFECTLY! <3 REQUEST CLOSE

Answer (score 0):

onsubmit was wrong function call change like this `onsubmit="return ValidCaptcha(event);"` .And also pass the event with `onsubmit`.Then only `e.preventDeafult()` is working

you could use [`trim()`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiUs9v705_UAhVGqI8KHXVFB1EQFgg8MAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FString%2Ftrim&usg=AFQjCNHplwP8uGVxgtKYMhsiv7EE8F9cMw&sig2=sqqPzVJG6KQe67641jOBTg) for remove unwanted spaces.

**Javascript**

```
function ValidCaptcha(e) {
  var str1 = document.getElementById('txtCaptcha').value.trim();
  var str2 = document.getElementById('txtCompare').value.trim();

  if (str1 == str2) {
    alert("請按OKAY兩次 (Please Press OKAY Twice To Submit)");
    document.getElementById('contact-form').action = "/send_form_email.php";
  } 
  else
  {
    alert("請輸入正確的號碼 (Please Enter The Correct Vertification Number)");
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
  }
}
```

**Html**

```
<form id="contact-form" class="form-horizontal" method="post" onsubmit="return ValidCaptcha(event);">
```

Comment: THIS CODE ALSO WORKS! I bet i look so stupid for trying to return and alert via ONSUBMIT! XD Many thanks <3